# How to split complex text file in C#?

Tags: c#, text, split

I have a text file as below and I want to get only the numbers below column rank:

```
SKYRain  LND(4)    VA(x)      ZZ(x)     NUM(n)   Rank  ll ListOfNames                                                   
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------   ----  -- -----------                                                   
   1002      75   283680     185836   1,111.50  19268   1 Jack                         
   4308    1100   175896     195404     751.70   6384   1 Sara                                                      
   3070     252  1044788     884160     682.94  18924   1 Robert                                                        
   3187     206   852280      97932     535.83  16472   1 Harry
```

I just want the numbers below the rank below:

```
19268
6384
18924
16472
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, there is a way and it's pretty simple. And your text file is not complex. It has fixed width columns

Comment: @ThomasWeller Well, there is a long distance between them, I tried to fill the space with a letter and then split them, but I couldn't

Comment: Why do you think it's easier to split on a letter instead of a space?

Comment: You don't even need to split at all. You could just use fixed index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fixed width text file. Just can simply use SubString():

```cs
public class Program{
    public static void Main(){
        string aLineOfYourTextFile = "   1002      75   283680     185836   1,111.50  19268   1 Jack ";
        Console.WriteLine(aLineOfYourTextFile.Substring(48,5));
    }
}
```

You can also use Split():

```cs
public class Program{
    public static void Main(){
        string aLineOfYourTextFile = "   1002      75   283680     185836   1,111.50  19268   1 Jack ";
        var columns = aLineOfYourTextFile.Split(new[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Console.WriteLine(columns[5]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the numbers and distances are not fixed and change in later times

Comment: @Inferno The Split() method should still work

Comment: While I believe reading the file as regular CSV is much better option (and I picked duplicate for that), indeed String.Split is an approach to this particular case. @Inferno please note that it is expected to try things out before asking a question (including asking for clarification in the comment) - I don't see why you still have that question after running the code suggested by Thomas Weller.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The second code worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- read and skip 2 lines
- read next line, split on " ", select 5th entry, convert to int
- repeat above till EOF